# Bluetooth repeatedly switching on and off, no audio, broken behavior

Tags: sound, 22.04, bluetooth, mouse, 22.10

I have some really odd behavior with bluetooth. There are a few seemingly related issues that are all resolved by rebooting Ubuntu- haven't found any other solution, and I've tried a fresh OS install.

- repeatedly and rapidly connecting/disconnecting my wireless mouse while mouse is unresponsive
- audio devices refuse to connect (e.g. connect then instantly disconnect)
- Device connected and audio is visualized in device settings, but no audio played
- Really odd mouse scroll wheel behavior: say I'm scrolling down as usual. Scrolling up once has no effect, and I have to click it up one more to make it scroll up once. Also happens in the reverse direction, so it's almost like a null zone or looseness, if that makes sense. Seems to be caused by the mouse going into sleep mode?

**Hardware**:
Laptop: Asus Zenbook UX3402ZA (dual-booted w/Windows 11)
Devices: Katar Pro Wireless (when on bluetooth mode - USB dongle mode is non-problematic), JLab Studio headset, generic custom printed "lantern speaker"

**Software**:
Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on SSD, 22.10 installed on SD card (kernel 5.19.0-38-generic)

I believe the problems don't happen on a live USB boot of the two OSs, and I've never had the problem my Windows 11 side, but I'm having a really hard time finding a pattern of cause and solution (other than, the issues sometimes happen at boot, and are usually resolved by rebooting - possibly related to the laptop and/or mouse going to sleep).

Output of `systemctl status bluetooth` (while issue is not present; will try again when issue shows up again)

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2023-03-26 09:29:17 MDT; 11min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 879 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 8994)
     Memory: 2.3M
        CPU: 2.456s
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─879 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Mar 26 09:30:33 ubtest-Zenbook-UX3402ZA-Q409ZA bluetoothd[879]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.75 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/faststream_duplex
Mar 26 09:30:33 ubtest-Zenbook-UX3402ZA-Q409ZA bluetoothd[879]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.75 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/opus_05
Mar 26 09:30:33 ubtest-Zenbook-UX3402ZA-Q409ZA bluetoothd[879]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.75 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/opus_05
Mar 26 09:30:33 ubtest-Zenbook-UX3402ZA-Q409ZA bluetoothd[879]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.75 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/opus_05_51
Mar 26 09:30:33 ubtest-Zenbook-UX3402ZA-Q409ZA bluetoothd[879]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.75 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/opus_05_71
Mar 26 09:30:33 ubtest-Zenbook-UX3402ZA-Q409ZA bluetoothd[879]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.75 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/opus_05_duplex
Mar 26 09:30:33 ubtest-Zenbook-UX3402ZA-Q409ZA bluetoothd[879]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.75 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/opus_05_duplex
Mar 26 09:30:33 ubtest-Zenbook-UX3402ZA-Q409ZA bluetoothd[879]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.75 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/opus_05_pro
Mar 26 09:31:32 ubtest-Zenbook-UX3402ZA-Q409ZA bluetoothd[879]: src/device.c:device_set_wake_support() Unable to set wake_support without RPA resolut>
Mar 26 09:31:32 ubtest-Zenbook-UX3402ZA-Q409ZA bluetoothd[879]: src/adapter.c:set_device_privacy_complete() Set device flags return status: Invalid P>
lines 1-22/22 (END)
```

Output of `neofetch`

```
OS: Ubuntu 22.10 x86_64
Host: Zenbook UX3402ZA_Q409ZA 1.0
Kernel: 5.19.0-38-generic 
Uptime: 3 mins 
Packages: 1527 (dpkg), 11 (snap) 
Shell: bash 5.2.2 
Resolution: 2880x1800 
DE: GNOME 43.1 
WM: Mutter 
WM Theme: Adwaita
Theme: Yaru-dark [GTK2/3] 
Icons: Yaru-dark [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: gnome-terminal 
CPU: 12th Gen Intel i5-1240P (16) @ 4.400GHz
GPU: Intel Alder Lake-P 
Memory: 2710MiB / 7570MiB
```

**Update 0:**

- No signs of the speaker/audio problems anymore, possibly resolved by the fresh install or *maybe* the lack of pulseeffects (I happen to not have reinstalled my EQ stuff yet).
- The scroll behavior problems seem to not happen on live images but can be triggered on full install OSs by complete inactivity for a few minutes (the laptop screen doesn't have to time out for this to happen).
- The connect/disconnect loop seems to happen only on a full install but can happen immediately after booting up. Comes/goes at random.

Comment: Please no pictures of text. Cut and paste into the body of the question. Makes it easier to read, prevents info cut off and makes it possible to search.

Comment: @David ah sorry, forgot about that - should be fixed now. Let me know if anything else is missing.

Comment: Do these problem also reoccur when running a live Ubuntu session from the bootable USB that you used to install Ubuntu?

Comment: @karel Although so far I can't pinpoint a way to intentionally trigger them, they seem to not be happening on the live boot - will update if they do begin to show up.